# Python: Improving run-time: Choosing two movie_lengths whose total_untimes will equal the exact flight length

Tags: python, runtime

I am working through another interview Question, and it is about the following coding interview question.

So I'm building a feature for choosing two movies whose total runtimes will equal the exact flight length.

The question asks the following:
Write a function that takes an integer flight_length (in minutes) and a list of integers movie_lengths (in minutes) and returns a boolean indicating whether there are two numbers in movie_lengths whose sum equals flight_length.

I first thought we can do through nest two loops (the outer choosing first_movie_length, the inner choosing second_movie_length). That’d give us a runtime of O(n^2)O(n2)

But is it possible that we can do better?

I have the following solution:

```
  def can_two_movies_fill_flight(movie_lengths, flight_length):

# movie lengths we've seen so far
movie_lengths_seen = set()

for first_movie_length in movie_lengths:

    matching_second_movie_length = flight_length - first_movie_length
    if matching_second_movie_length in movie_lengths_seen:
        return True

    movie_lengths_seen.add(first_movie_length)

# we never found a match, so return False
return False
```

I think this solution gives me O(n) time, and O(n) O(n) space.

Is it possible that I can use hash map?

Comment: is there a more optimized solution?

Comment: I see. it seems like that we can use set to optimize the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could sort the movie_lengths first—then we could use binary search to find second_movie_length in O(\lg{n})O(lgn) time instead of O(n)O(n) time.
 But sorting would cost O(nlg(n))O(nlg(n)), and we can do even better than that.

My Solution:
Using a set as our data structure. 
We make one pass through movie_lengths, treating each item as the first_movie_length. At each iteration.

See if there is a matching_second_movie_length we've seen already (stored in our movie_lengths_seen set) that is equal to flight_length - first_movie_length. If there is, we short-circuit and return True.
Keep our movie_lengths_seen set up to date by throwing in the current first_movie_length.

```
  def can_two_movies_fill_flight(movie_lengths, flight_length):

    # movie lengths we&#39;ve seen so far
    movie_lengths_seen = set()

    for first_movie_length in movie_lengths:

        matching_second_movie_length = flight_length - first_movie_length
        if matching_second_movie_length in movie_lengths_seen:
            return True

        movie_lengths_seen.add(first_movie_length)

    return False
```

We know users won't watch the same movie twice because we check movie_lengths_seen for matching_second_movie_length before we've put first_movie_length in it!

Efficiency and Algorithmic complexity: O(n)O(n) time, and O(n)O(n) space. Note while optimizing runtime we added a bit of space cost.